# pass JQuery Variable in a Form Dynamically

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to pass a jQuery variable through a Form, but I keep getting an error. How can I pass the values variable correctly. When I pass it to the next page, it spits out the intialized variable and does not change, when I change the slider. How can I get this to change?

```
            <input id="column" type="hidden" name="column" value="";>

<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
        range: true,
        min: 0,
        max: 500,
        values: [ 75, 300 ],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
                    $( "#values" ).val(ui.values[ 0 ]);

        }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
        " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );

    $( "#column" ).val($( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ));


});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see any element with an id="values"

Answer (score 1):

your id selector is wrong, also please note you are setting the value of slider instead of getting, try this:

```
<input id="column" type="hidden" name="column" value="";/>
```

```
$("#column").val($("#slider-range").slider("value"));
```

or:

```
$("#slider-range").slider({
   change: function(event, ui) { 
      $("#column").val($("#slider-range").slider("option", "value"));
   }
});
```

Comment: That almost works, except it doesn't change dynamically. It only submits the initial value. Code Below. Can you help?

Comment: Guys, it almost works; It just doesn't work dynamically. Can someone please help?

Comment: @user1446797 this should work, what is the problem? http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-change

Comment: Guys, the slider works. The problem is that the variable passed is what the variable was initialized to initially. This value changes with the slider, but it only passes through the initialized variable. What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First off, it's a good idea to put quotes around all of the values for attributes.

`id=myTable --> id="myTable"`

Second, your selector is wrong. The ID of the field is `column` not `values`

```
$( "#column").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
```

Comment: Guys, it almost works; It just doesn't work dynamically. Can someone please help? I edited the code above

Comment: might need to move it to the `slide: function()` function

Comment: Guys, the slider works. The problem is that the variable passed is what the variable was initialized to initially. This value changes with the slider, but it only passes through the initialized variable. What's the problem? Ie, it only passes throught 45, as this is what it's initialized to.

Comment: That's because it only gets set once. You need to set the value (using the line in my solution) every time the slider changes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any element with id="values", perhaps you want to pass the value to element with  id="column"

```
$("#column").val($( "#slider-range" ).slider("value"));
```

and remove the value=values; part of the HTML code, simply `value=""`

Comment: Guys, it almost works; It just doesn't work dynamically. Can someone please help? I edited the code above.

Comment: Guys, the slider works. The problem is that the variable passed is what the variable was initialized to initially. This value changes with the slider, but it only passes through the initialized variable. What's the problem?